# Find the hidden word

Tags: word

I met a traveller from an antique land

Who said: "Two vast and trunkless legs of stone

Stand on the desert. Near them, over his sand,

Half sunk, a shatter'd visage lies, whose gown,

And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,

Tell that its sculptor well those passions read

Which yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things,

The head that mocked them and the heart that fed:

And over the pedestal these words appear:

'My name is Ozymandias, king of kings:

Look on my words, ye Mighty, and despair!'

Nothing beside remain. Round the decay

Of that colossal wreck, boundless and bare

The lone and level sands stretch far away.

> [Shelley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias)

Comment: that's "frown", not "gown"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I met a traveller from an antique land
>
> Who said: "Two vast and trunkless legs of stone
>
> Stand  [<s>o</s> **i**]n the desert. Near them, o[<s>ver</s> **n**] [**t**]h[<s>is</s> **e**] sand,
>
> Half sunk, a shatter[**e**]d visage lies, whose [<s>g</s> **fr**]own,
>
> And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,
>
> Tell that its sculptor well those passions read
>
> Which yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things,
>
> The h[<s>ea</s> **an**]d that mocked them and the heart that fed:
>
> And o[<s>ver</s> **n**] the pedestal these words appear:
>
> 'My name is Ozymandias, king of kings:
>
> Look on my wor[<s>d</s> **k**]s, ye Mighty, and despair!'
>
> Nothing beside remain[**s**]. Round the decay
>
> Of that colossal wreck, boundless and bare
>
> The lone and level sands stretch far away.
>
>
> gives **i,n,t,e,e,f,r,a,n,n,k,s**
>
>
> which is an anagram of **Frankenstein**
>
>
> written, of course, by Shelley's wife, *[Mary Shelley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Shelley)*.

Comment: You're missing an 'e' somewhere, though this definitely looks right to me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Rise to greatness on the shoulders of giants...

> Removing all of the letters that exist in your new words but not in the existing words we get the following letters...
>
> o ver is g e ver d

Rearranging this a bit we get...

> grover is eved

As everyone knows...

> Eved is a poetic term for peved...

This clearly indicates the identity of Ozymandias to be none other than...

> Grover the lovable blue muppet.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start trying to solve it, it still doesn't make much sense to me:

> It's a known poem by Shelley
> These following words have been changed: on/(in) over/(on), his/(the), gown/(frown), head/(hand), over/(on), words/(works)
>
> overisgeverd / intefrnnk (overisgdntfrk) << characters differing in words changed
> oversgevdntfnnk (oversgdntfk)  << characters differing in the differing characters OF the words changed
>  **Rei** << Characters common to the characters differing in the words changed, lol
>
> Common letters in words changed are nohownhadowors or n, o, h, w, a, d, s, r
>  a, d, s, r << unique characters in common letters of words changed. I could make : *Rads*
> I guess it could be *how's rand* and you'd be inquiring after rand in this puzzle of yours.
> Or *Owon Shadowhorn* the great hunter of Jawas. *A honor showdown*

or again:

> letters of original words: inthefrowadks
> letters of new words: onverhisgwad

Lol

Comment: on the right track :)

Comment: ...you are missing some BTW ;)

Comment: I think I was missing an 'n'   doesn't reallyu change much though

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't get what you could be asking. But now I think you mean:

> When compared with the original poem, I highlighted the words which were changed in the post from the original poem:
>
> I met a traveller from an antique land
>
> Who said: "Two vast and trunkless legs of stone
>
> Stand **on** the desert. Near them, **over his** sand,
>
> Half sunk, a shatter'd visage lies, whose **gown**,
>
> And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,
>
> Tell that its sculptor well those passions read
>
> Which yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things,
>
> The **head** that mocked them and the heart that fed:
>
> And **over** the pedestal these words appear:
>
> 'My name is Ozymandias, king of kings:
>
> Look on my **words**, ye Mighty, and despair!'
>
> Nothing beside remain. Round the decay
>
> Of that colossal wreck, boundless and bare
>
> The lone and level sands stretch far away.
>
> Which seems to refer to the **Egyptian pharaoh headdress**. (Possibly related to Ramesses II)

Source:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias

Comment: right idea :) ${}
{}{}{}$

Comment: Head over words.....head over gown.....head over heels?!? Maybe I'm just getting a-head of myself.

Comment: not much to do with heads, I'm afraid!

Comment: ... or Egypt, come to that ...